# How to rotate 2d-matrix that is packed into 1d array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, matrix

im working on a tetris game and im keeping block maps in following format in an xml file.

```
<block column="2">101011</block>
```

then im parsing this xml into 1d array as follows

boolean[] bitmap=new boolean[]{true,false,true,false,true,true}; //101011 in boolean in java

afterwards while drawing tetris block im using column number and this 1d array to calculate the coordinate of each block.
which then displays "L" block

10
10
11

now... i want to rotate these blocks... what i need to is:(for ccw)
101011
to
001111
and column number 2 to 3

Comment: Isn't that just flipping the bits two by two? 101011 -> 010111

Comment: not 101011 -> 010111
 :) 101011 -> 001111

Comment: @deporter i implementing the code right now :) but it looks like it's going to work so i voted +1 and will accept answer after i see it works :)

Comment: @AhmetYıldırım you can also parametrize it, for instance defining your 2d array as int[x][y] and your 1d array as int[x*y], i can change the code or you can handle it yourself.

Comment: thanks :) it's ok this way , i added it as a method to tetris block object :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for traversing over a 2dD array such that your desired 1D array is created:

```
int[][] array = new int[][] { { 1, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };
int[] newArray = new int[6];
int index = 0;

// Populating 1D array.
for (int i = array[0].length; i > 0; i--)
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
        newArray[index++] = array[j][i - 1];

// See the contents of 1D array.
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++)
    System.out.println(newArray[i]);
```